# When are packages released on packages.ubuntu.com?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, packaging, github

I have often observed this: A release of a package has long been made on Github, but if I upgrade it with apt, it is not found. Example:

https://github.com/libgeos/geos : They show that 3.9 has already been released for Ubuntu.

sudo apt-get install --upgrade libgeos-dev, however, gives me 3.8.0-1build1.

Is there a special cause for this? Why do not people upload their code so that it can get installed by apt?

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu is not a rolling release.

Comment: Does [this](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management) help answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks. So I either have to install newer versions manually or wait until the next Ubuntu release. Which is long, but okay.

Comment: One more question: What means "next Ubuntu release"? I am only using the LTS versions. Will I have to wait more than one year now if I do not want to build it manually fromn source?

Comment: @MaxH.Balsmeier, yes, the LTS is released every 2 years.  sometimes there is a user created repository (often on launchpad), but there doesn't appear to be one for libgeos (I checked)

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: The (original) purpose of an LTS release is to avoid breaking enterprise workflows by changing software versions every six months. Those folks WANT older software. Since you want newer software, consider migrating to the normal 6-month releases of Ubuntu, which go through the same QA process, are just as stable, and have newer software.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider that.